# How to use CSV Data Set Config can any one guide me Step by step

Tags: jmeter

I am new user to j-meter and try to record some script; I have done some recording with Firefox 
Now i want to record script for Multiple log-in at one time how can i do that with **"CSV Data Set Config"** can any one guide me step by step

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the link below:

http://ivetetecedor.com/how-to-use-a-csv-file-with-jmeter/

hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

1. Just add a [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) test element as a child of the request which performs login
2. Make sure that your parent [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) has enough virtual users and/or loops
3. And you're following steps from [Using CSV DATA SET CONFIG](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/65138-using-csv-data-set-config) guide.y